# Access Denied - S3 Index Document

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, static-site

I've uploaded multiple pages to S3 to host a static website. Individually, they load fine.

```
https://s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/MYDOMAIN/services
```

For example, will load the services page. Clicking Contact will load the contact page.

However, if I try to navigate to root, i.e.

```
https://s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/MYDOMAIN/
```

I get

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
```

Any advice would be great. S3 is driving me insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Bucket and **right-click** on **object or whole folder** then **Make Public**

Then **Refresh**

---

from this answer [Access Denied for index.html Amazon S3 static website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041381/access-denied-for-index-html-amazon-s3-static-website)

> You can see your endpoint by going to S3 > Click on your bucket > Bucket Properties > Static website hosting > should reveal your endpoint.

Comment: after adding some files, you should Make them Public

Comment: Tried - Still no luck.